# ¿como actulizar registros de una base de datos despues de realizar la consulta?

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy haciendo la actualizacion de datos  de un registro en mi base de datos pero antes necesito obtener los datos de ese registro en sus campos 
respectivos esta es mi base datos.

```
Field             type         key   default
servicio_No       int(11)      PRI     NULL
tipo_Ambulancia   Varchar(5)           NULL
tipo_Traslado     varchar(20)          NUll
cliente           varchar(45)          NULL
fecha_Solicitud   date                 NULL
```

consultar.php

```
    <html>

<head>
    <title>Inicio Consulta.</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html"; charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilos.css">

</head>
<body class="body">

            <form class="form" method="POST" action="servicioConsultado.php">

              <h1>Consultando Servicio</h1>

                    <label>Servicio No: </label>

                    <input type="text" REQUIRED name="id" size="20" class="input">           

                    <input type="submit" value="Consultar" name="btn-consultar" class="submit">                                     
       </form>

</body>
</html>
```

formatoModificacion.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Consultando Servicio...</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html"; charset="utf-8">
</head>
<?php 
echo "<body>";
//Conexion a la base de datos
$conexion =  mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","admin123","database");
//Validamos la conexion a la base de datos
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo 'Fallo la conexion a la base de datos';
}
//Limpiamos y Recibimos por POST los datos procedentes del formulario 
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['id']);

    $query = "SELECT servicio_No, hora, tipo_Ambulancia, tipo_Traslado, horario, cliente, fecha_Solicitud FROM servicio WHERE servicio_No = ?";
    /*Prepara la setencia SQl para su ejecucion*/
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conexion, $query)) {

    /*Agrega variables a una sentencia preparada como parametros*/
    /* ligar parámetros para marcadores */
    /*IMPORTANTE: Si id no es numérico en la base de datos, cambia la i por una s*/
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $id);

    /* Ejecuta una consulta preparada */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    /*Se transfiere los  resultados de la ultima consulta*/
    $stmt->store_result();

    /* Vincula las variables a una setencia preparada para el almacenamineto de result */
    $stmt->bind_result($servicio_No, $hora, $tipo_Ambulancia, $tipo_Traslado, $horario, $cliente, $fecha_Solicitud);
     while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        echo "
     <body class='body'>
        <h1>Regulacion</h1>
        <form method='POST' action='modificarServicio.php'  class='form'>

    <label>Servicio No:<input type='text' name='servicio_No' value='".$servicio_No."' style='width: 2%'></label>


    <label style='margin-left: 1%'>Tipo Ambulancia:</label>
        <select name='tipo_Ambulancia'>
            <option value='".$tipo_Ambulancia."'>TAB</option>   
            <option value='".$tipo_Ambulancia."'>TAM</option>
        </select></br>

    <br><label>Tipo Traslado:</label>
        <select name='tipo_Traslado'>
            <option value='".$tipo_Traslado."'>Simple</option>
            <option value='".$tipo_Traslado."'>Doble</option>
            <option value='".$tipo_Traslado."'>Asistencia</option>
            <option value='".$tipo_Traslado."'>Evento</option>
        </select>
    <label style='margin-left: 1%'>Cliente:</label>
    <select name='cliente'>
        <option value='".$cliente."'>Particular</option>
        <option value='".$cliente."'>EMP Medisanitas</option>
        <option value='".$cliente."'>ARL Colmena</option>
        <option value='".$cliente."'>AXA</option>
        <option value='".$cliente."'>PEPS Sanitas</option>
        <option value='".$cliente."'>San Esteban</option>
        <option value='".$cliente."'>EMP Colsanitas</option>
        <option value='".$cliente."'>HSVF Medellin</option>
        <option value='".$cliente."'>Hospital Pablo Tobon Uribe</option>
        <option value='".$cliente."'>Seguros De Vida Suramerica</option>
        <option value='".$cliente."'>EPM</option>
        <option value='".$cliente."'>Clinica Rosario</option>
        <option value='".$cliente."'>Coosalud</option>
        <option value='".$cliente."'>HSVF Rionegro</option>
        <option value='".$cliente."'>Clinica Sagrado Corazon</option>
        <option value='".$cliente."'>Sky Ambulance</option>
        <option value='".$cliente."'>Quirofanos el tesoro</option>
    </select>

    <label style='margin-left: 1%'>Fechar Solicitud:<input type='text' name='fecha_Solicitud' value='".$fecha_Solicitud."'></label>
    <input type='submit' value='Modificar' class='submit'>
    </form>  
    ";
    } 

}else{
    echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0; URL=http://localhost/Aeroasistencia/Servicios/consultarServicio.php">
         <script>
                    alert("El servicio no existe");
         </script>';
}
//Cerramos la conexion con la base de datos
mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

modificarServicio.php

```
     <?php
    //Conexion a la base de datos
    $conexion =  mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "admin123", "database");
    //Validamos la conexion a la base de datos
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo 'Fallo la conexion a la base de datos';
    }
                ////Limpiamos y Recibimos por POST los datos procedentes del formulario 
                $servicio_No = $_POST['servicio_No'];
                $tipo_Ambulancia = $_POST['tipo_Ambulancia'];
                $tipo_Traslado = $_POST['tipo_Traslado'];
                $cliente = $_POST['cliente'];
                $fecha_Solicitud = date('Y-m-d');

    mysqli_query($conexion,"UPDATE servicio SET servicio_No ='$servicio_No', 
                                                            tipo_Ambulancia = '$tipo_Ambulancia', 
                                                            tipo_Traslado = '$tipo_Traslado', 

                                                            cliente = '$cliente',
                                                            fecha_Solicitud = '$fecha_Solicitud', 
                                                            WHERE 
                                                            servicio_No = '$servicio_No'") or die("ERROR AL ACTUALIZAR");

    mysqli_close($conexion);                                                            
?>                      
                <META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0; URL=http://localhost/Aeroasistencia/Servicios/index.php">
                <script>
                    alert("Se ha ACTULIZADO CORRECTAMENTE");

                </script>
```

Comment: El problema son los <select> ya que estos no obteniendo el datos del registro y al momento de actulizarlos no realizan el cambio en  la base de datos.

Comment: Estas construyendo mal los select.  Les estas poniendo el mismo value a todas las opciones.

Comment: @alanfcm puedes mostrarme como serian?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema esta en como estas construyendo los `select`.  Les estas poniendo el mismo `value` a todas las opciones.  Te dejo un ejemplo con la primera opcion:

```
<select name='cliente'>
    <option value='Particular' " 
        . ($cliente == 'Particular' ? "selected" : "") . ">Particular</option>
                 // Aqui van todas las otras opciones
                 // con un formato similar
                 // 
</select>
```

Asi tendrias que construir todas las otras opciones.

Comment: voy hacerlo de esa manera muchas gracias

Comment: como puedo hacer que el <select> se alimenten de la base de datos cada que exista un registro nuevo pero al mismo tiempo me obtengan la opcion registrada.

Comment: En ese caso tendrias que hacer queries separadas para cada campo e iterar los resultados de cada una y asi construir el HTML

Comment: <?php  

  $sentencia = "SELECT NIT, nombre_Cliente FROM cliente ORDER BY NIT";
  $query = mysqli_query($conexion,$sentencia);

    ?>

Comment: <label style="margin-left: 1%">Cliente:</label>
  <select name="cliente">
      <?php while ($arreglo = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $arreglo['nombre_Cliente']?>"><?php echo $arreglo ['nombre_Cliente']?></option>
      <?php } ?>         
     </select>

Comment: Si, se ve bien.

Comment: PERO HAY NO SE COMO PONER PARA OBTENER LA OPCION SELECCIONADA QUE SE ENCUENTRA REGISTRADA

Comment: Igual que en mi respuesta, solo que vas a comparar la variable `$cliente` con `$arreglo['nombre_Cliente']`

Comment: NO TE ENTIENDO MUY BIEN COMO HACERLO? NO ME FUNCIONA